# Quitar Git init de desktop

Tags: git

[image]

Sin querer puse un git init en el desktop entero, como hago para que deje de estar en master/main de mi desktop

Comment: borra la carpeta .git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para eliminar los repositorios de un proyecto o de cualquier carpeta basta con eliminar la carpeta oculta .git y el archivo .gitignore en caso de exista:

```
rm -rf .git
rm .gitignore
```

Espero te ayude saludos.